# pop-up on mouse hovering angularjs

Tags: angularjs

When user done entering the text in input, a validation needs to be done. I tried using `ng-mouseleave` It's working slow. Below HTML code with the change

```
<input id="{{title}}_filter_component_search" set-init-value="{{initValue}}" type="text" ng-mouseleave="change()"  ng-model="searchCtrl.value" typeahead="{{typeahead}}" typeahead-template-url="{{typeaheadTemplateUrl}}"
                       class="form-control" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" typeahead-on-select="onSelect($item, $model, $label)">
```

Comment: ok, so whats the problem?

Comment: Ok, so I'm pretty sure I'm missing something obvious, but I'm not seeing it.

I created a fiddle that I would have thought would throw an alert message when the input box loses focus, but it's not working and I don't know why.

I was expecting an alert message when the user performs the following steps:

click the input box
type something
click somewhere outside of the input box
but these steps do not show an alert message.

Here's the code:                                     $scope.change =function(){
     alert("test");
    }

Answer (score 0):

You should ng-blur. The ng-blur directive tells AngularJS what to do when an HTML element loses focus.

```
<input id="{{title}}_filter_component_search" set-init-value="{{initValue}}" 
type="text" ng-blur="change()" ng-model="searchCtrl.value" typeahead="
{{typeahead}}" typeahead-template-url="{{typeaheadTemplateUrl}}" 
class="form-control" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" 
typeahead-on-select="onSelect($item, $model, $label)">
```